# How to remove Analytics' DoubleClick (for demographic data)?

Tags: google-analytics

Over a week ago I [enabled demographic reports](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872) in Google Analytics. A day later, I changed my mind and disabled this feature in my Analytics property.

However, `analytics.js` today still makes two redirects to the `stats.g.doubleclick.net` domain. How can I turn off demographic data collecting in Google Analytics?

(The *Enable Demographics and Interest Reports* option in my Analytics property is turned off.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem is solved now; the `analytics.js` JavaScript file doesn't redirect to `stats.g.doubleclick.net` for demographic data collection anymore.

As it turns out, disabling the 'Enable Demographics and Interest Reports' option in the property settings is not enough to remove data being send to DoubleClick; the 'Advertising Reporting Features' option below Tracking Info -> Data Collection needs to be turned off also.

In my case, this latter option was enabled after turning on the demographic reports, but wasn't disabled when I turned off demographic reports.

Visually, my settings are now:

[image: demographic options turned off]

And this option is what I overlooked:

[image]

Comment: Strange, I have everything off on both pages yet still seeing doubleclick in the network tab when viewing the site

Comment: unlink any google ad account from google analytics account! Google is unfortunately more and more connecting adWords and adSense with Ganalytics

Comment: @Titan also add this command after loading the GA file `ga('set', 'displayFeaturesTask', null);`

Answer (score 0):

The display features plugin for analytics.js can be used to enable Display Advertising Features in Google Analytics, such as Remarketing, Demographics and Interest Reporting, and more. Learn more about Display Advertising Features in Google Analytics [https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3450482](http://wordpressgeekhelp.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/about-advertising-features.html)

In the past, this functionality required using the dc.js tag. In Universal Analytics, these features are enabled via a plugin. To load the plugin, add a require call to your code snippet, specifying the displayfeatures plugin:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Refer to the display features developer guide for more detailed implementation information.

Comment: I don't want to _enable_ Demographics. I want to turn it off.